# jQuery backstretch plugin , remembering last displayed background

Tags: jquery

I am using backstretch plugin as a slideshow on my website.

```
var images = [
"images/bg6.jpg"
, "images/bg5.jpg"
, "images/bg2.jpg"
, "images/bg.jpg"
, "images/bg4.jpg"
, "images/bg3.jpg"
];
```

These are my background images:

Slideshow starts with `bg6.jpg` and goes like `bg5...bg2...bg...` (same order in array).. between 10 seconds. Think that current displayed image is `bg4.jpg`. And visitor refreshed the page. It normally starts from beginning. I want the plugin to start from the last displayed background.

I worked on it a little bit, I can create that part (the one I copy-pasted) dynamically, but the problem is,how can I get the "current displayed background image" from backstretch jQuery plugin.

So, is there a way to get the current image which is being displayed by jQuery? If I am able to get it, I can set it from ASP.NET and after refresh, backstretch will start with that image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(document).unload(function(){

var lstimg = //Get your last image URL from DOM or whatever.jpg
document.location.href + "#" + lstimg;

});

$(document).load(function(){

//Make your code to look at #hash then to start from that image on document load

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this...

 <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {               
            $.backstretch([
             "images/bg6.jpg",
             "images/bg5.jpg",
             "images/bg2.jpg",
             "images/bg.jpg",
             "images/bg4.jpg",
             "images/bg3.jpg"
            ], {
                fade: 1000,
                duration: 8000
            });
        });
    </script>
```